# Backbone.js templating examples

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

How to add radio button as an attribute to model and view it in a template.

```
<label>ModemControl:</label>
 <input type="radio" name="modemcontrol" value="0" checked="checked"> off
                        <input type="radio" name="modemcontrol" value="1"> on
```

i have already completed creating labels,dropdownbox,textbox.i have no idea how to do this can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right you are interested in checking the right radio button on some attributes in the model.

In this case your template should look like somewhat:

```
<script type="text/template" id="radio-template">
    <input type="radio" <% f == "opt1" ? print("checked") :'' %> >
    <input type="radio" <% f == "opt2" ? print("checked") :'' %> >
    ...
</script>
```

where f is the template variable you specified during the view setup, like:

```
var template = _.template($('#item-template').html(), {f: 'opt2'});
this.$el.html(template);
```

Not that you can either use only `checked` or `checked="true"`

**EDIT**

Then your template should look like:

```
<script type="text/template">
    <label>Age:</label> <input type="text" name="age" value="<%= age %>">
    <label>Radio:</label> <input type="radio" value="<%= modelAttribute%>">
</script>
```

Comment: wat u r telling s for checking i have to jus create radio buttons tat s enough.

Comment: I created two radio button in the above example. You mean, you have to create radio buttons dynamically?

Comment: without checking can u tel me how to add radio buttons as model attributes and viewing it in a template Person = Backbone.Model.extend({}); var person = new Person({ name: 'Thomas', age: 37 }), //in template// <label>Age:</label> <input type="text" name="age" value="<%= age %>"> now age text box will be added now i wan like this to create radio buttons

Comment: @user2082957 I edited my answer. I'm not sure that I completely understood your question.