# Creating radio buttons in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

How to add radio button with label name age and 2 values  0 :on 1: 0ff  and view it in a template.

```
<label>age:</label>
     <input type="radio" name="age" value="0" checked="checked"> off
     <input type="radio" name="age" value="1"> on
```

I want this to be added as an attribute to model and view it in template. Can anyone help? I know the basics of backbone.js.

i did like this below  for dropdown box.

```
 $(function(){
    var person = new Person({baudrate:{4:1200,5:2400,6:4800,7:9600,8:19200}});
    app = new View({model: person});
        app.render();
    View = Backbone.View.extend({
el: "#form",
render: function() {
    var html = _.template($('#form-tpl').html(), this.model.toJSON());
    this.$el.html(html);
} 
});
    <script type="text/template" id="form-tpl">
     <label>Baud Rate:</label>
    <select id="baudrate">
                              <% for (var key in baudrate) { %>
                                 <option value="<%=key%>"><%=baudrate[key]%></option>
                                  <% } %>
                       </select>

 </script>
```

Comment: Currently what you need ? Do you need to display in jsp page or HTML.

Comment: Please don't open multiple questions with the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15243973/backbone-js-templating-examples/15244990 You can always edit your old question.

Comment: ok sorry for it...now i have edited my code.i wan to add radio buttons as model attributes then view it in a template

Comment: Is this what you need? http://jsfiddle.net/CX3ud/1/

Comment: yes..but i have one doubt cudn't we pass age:{0:'On',1:'Off'} like this in model n then view it in template as its for dropdown box

Comment: can u tel me wat exactly 'checked' do here?